# Update Button for Access Database via DataGridView Using OLEDB in VB.NET (Visual Studio 2013)

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, oledb

I have linked an Access database to my program. It populates the DataGridView as it is intended to so that part of the program works. However the new data that i add to my DataGridView wont show up and I don't know what is wrong with my code.

Can anyone see anything wrong or something I've missed out that would cause the code not to function as desired? Thank you in advance :)

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Public Class Form1
    Dim j As OleDbConnection
    Dim a As OleDbDataAdapter
    Dim s As DataSet
    Dim lokasidb As String
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Call jaringan()
        a = New OleDbDataAdapter("Select * From datadairy", j)
        s = New DataSet
        s.Clear()
        a.Fill(s, "datadairy")
        DataGridDairy.DataSource = (s.Tables("datadairy"))
    End Sub

    Private Sub eksekusiSql(ByVal Sql As String)
        Dim objcmd As New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand
        Call jaringan()
        Try
            objcmd.Connection = j
            objcmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
            objcmd.CommandText = Sql
            objcmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            objcmd.Dispose()
            MsgBox("The new data successfully saved", vbInformation)
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox("The new data is failed to save", vbInformation)
        End Try
    End Sub

    Sub jaringan()
        lokasidb = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\19106060045_Tugas Modul 5.accdb"
        j = New OleDbConnection(lokasidb)
        If j.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then j.Open()
    End Sub

    Private Sub ButtonAdd_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ButtonAdd.Click
        Dim No As String = TextNo.Text
        Dim Jenis_Susu_Sapi As String = TextSusu.Text
        Dim Jenis_Olahan As String = TextOlahan.Text
        Dim Harga_per_kg As String = TextHarga.Text
        Dim Tempat_Penjualan As String = TextPasar.Text
        Dim Sql_Simpan_Dairy As String = "Insert into datadairy (No, Jenis_Susu_Sapi, Jenis_Olahan, Harga_per_kg, Tempat_Penjualan) values (" + No + ",'" + Jenis_Susu_Sapi + "','" + Jenis_Olahan + "','" + Harga_per_kg + "','" + Tempat_Penjualan + "')"

        eksekusiSql(Sql_Simpan_Dairy)
        ShowDairydata()
    End Sub

    Public Sub ShowDairydata()
        Call jaringan()
        a = New OleDbDataAdapter("Select * from datadairy", j)
        s = New DataSet
        s.Clear()
        a.Fill(s, "datadairy")
        DataGridDairy.DataSource = (s.Tables("datadairy"))
    End Sub
```

Comment: If you populate a `DataTable` using a data adapter to display data then you should not be calling `ExecuteNonQuery` to save data. You should be making changes to the data in the `DataTable`, adding new rows, editing existing rows and deleting existing rows, then saving those changes back to the database by calling `Update` on the same data adapter.

Comment: Thats a great help from you but could you please write the code for me to change the `objcmd.ExecuteNonQuery` please? @jmcilhinney

Comment: You should do some research on the subject first and then ask for help if and when you run into a specific issue.

Comment: okay great, thanks a lot! @jmcilhinney

Answer (score 0):

After adding new data to your database, just use

'DataGridDairy.Databind()'

to refresh.